# Show that for any integer $n=1,..,32$ such that $(n,33) = 1$, $\left(\frac{n}{33}\right) = \left(\frac{33-n}{33}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Is there a way to verify this without going through all values of n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. The key fact is that $3$ and $11$ are both of the form $4k+3$.

The Jacobi symbol $(a/33)$ is *defined* as $(a/3)(a/11)$, where $(a/3)$ and $(a/11)$ are Legendre symbols.

Note that $((33-a)/3)=(-a/3)$ and $((33-a)/11)=(-a/11)$ by properties of the Legendre symbol. So we need to show that
$(a/3)(a/11)=(-a/3)(-a/11)$.

But $(-a/3)=(-1/3)(a/3)=-(a/3)$. For $(-1/3)=-1$, since $3$ is of the shape $4k+3$. Similarly, $(-a/11)=-(a/11)$, since $11$ is of the shape $4k+3$. The result follows.

**Remark:** We travelled through properties of the Legendre symbol. But we could have worked purely with standard properties of the Jacobi symbol, if those have already been derived. For $((33-a)/33)=(-a/33)=(-1/33)(a/33)$. But $(-1/33)=(-1/3)(-1/11)=(-1)(-1)=1$.

Comment: Did you mean that ((33−a)/11)=(−a/11) and not ((33−a)/11)=(−3/11)? How were you able to get ((33-a)/3) = (-a/3)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, than you, typo fixed. A general fact about the Legendre symbol is that if $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$ then $(a/p)=(b/p)$: $a$ is a QR of $p$ iff $b$ is a QR of $p$. And $33-a\equiv -a\pmod{3}$, also $33-a\equiv -a\pmod{11}$.

Comment: Does this result follow since $33 \bmod 3 \equiv 0$? Would, for example, ((7-p)/3) = (1-p)/3? Would that be the final form for this expression?

Comment: Yes, it is because $33\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. And yes, $((7-p)/3)=(((1-p)/3)$. There is no such thing as "final form" but there may be a best form for one's purposes.